# Mongoid add field but don't exist in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I use Mongoid to query db in a rails project.
When i add a field "scope" to a User Model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field   :scope,  type: String
end
```

When use rails console, we can find this field have add to User model.

But when we go to mongodb console to view users data, use `db.users.find()`, it don't have scope field yet.

also when i want update scope field in rails console. It always have below error.

```
pry(main)> user = User.first
=> #<User _id: 521dcd4464fad29a74000009, scope: "private", xxx_id: "521dcd4464fad29a74000008">
pry(main)> user.update_attributes(scope: "public")   
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=84
  @request_id=17
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="blog_development.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :safe=>true}
  @fields=nil>

failed with error 11000: "E11000 duplicate key error index: blog_development.users.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('521dcd4464fad29a74000009') }"
```

Any one can tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Just adding `field :scope,  type: String` to your model won't add it to the underlying MongoDB collection, that just tells Mongoid that it should allow the model to have a `scope` for accessors, mutators, validations, mass-assignment, ... Keep in mind that different documents in a MongoDB collection can have entirely different properties so the schema is really a fiction that is applied by Mongoid.

If you want all your `users` to have a `scope` then you'd have to say something like this:

```
User.collection.find().update_all(:$set => { :scope => 'whatever it should be' })
```

to manually add it to all the documents.

Answer (score 0):

The field exists in your saved objects. But to be able to find one with your asked value, you have to create one.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :age, type: Integer
end

User.find(name: 'John')
# => nil

User.create({ name: 'John', age: '18' })
# => User 284692 :name => 'John', :age => 18

User.find(name: 'John')
# => User 284692 :name => 'John', :age => 18
```

Hope it helps.

<strike>edit after 'mu is too short' post :

To fill all existing objects in db, just provide a :default value to your field</strike>

```
class User
  field :name, type: String, default: 'Martin Dupont'
end
```

Comment: Adding a default value won't do anything to existing documents in the collection though, the default value only affects new instances.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply.

The reason is in this model, i have overwrite `new_record?` method. So cause this error.